# debugging why a user can't do some things over ssh that can be done locally

Tags: ssh, rsync

This is a little difficult to explain so I will outline the problem as I see it.

I have two servers that I can log into via ssh using keys which work. I can log in without supplying a password.

The user can likewise do an "ls -l" via ssh without a problem, eg:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 "ls -l"
ssh user@192.168.1.11 "ls -l"
```

both work.

but doing something with rsync gives an error on one server:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 "rsync --version"  # works
ssh user@192.168.1.11 "rsync --version"  # doesn't work: permission denied
```

However that user if logged in directly to the server can run the command without a problem.

```
user@192.168.1.11:~$ rsync --version  #returns version information
```

I don't understand what exactly the problem is that would allow a user to do something locally and via ssh on one server, but not via ssh on another server 9and they can locally).

In as far as I can tell everything is identical, but obviously something isn't.

edit: typing:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 'which rsync --version'
ssh user@192.168.1.11 'which rsync --version'
```

yields identical `/usr/bin/rsync`

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 'echo "$PATH"'
ssh user@192.168.1.11 'echo "$PATH"'
```

yields identical `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

however logging into each machine gives a slightly different (but again identical):

```
`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin`
```

all rsync versions have the same permissions (this is identical on both servers, with the exception of the timestamp):

```
:~$ ls -l /bin/rsync /usr/bin/rsync
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 541760 May 10 07:48 /bin/rsync
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 541760 May 10 07:48 /usr/bin/rsync


21:39:20 user:~$ ssh mad@192.168.1.11 'echo "$PATH"'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
21:39:26 user:~$ ssh mad@192.168.1.11 "which rsync"
/usr/bin/rsync
21:39:37 user:~$ ssh mad@192.168.1.11 "rsync --version"
Permission denied, please try again.
21:39:47 user:~$ ssh mad@192.168.1.11 "/usr/bin/rsync --version"
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30...
...
```

I have been looking everywhere for any difference in the user setups and I cannot find anything. All permissions in as far as I can see are identical. The only thing I have found so far is that they are running slightly different versions of `sshd_config`:

work on this one:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.94 2015/02/02 01:57:44 deraadt Exp $
```

but not on this one:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $
```

The systems are identical however one is an older hardware version and both have the latest updates (I just ran an update to confirm).

The crux of the problem is I need to run `rsync` from another server to this server and it's rsync itself that is also getting permission denied, not just rsync via ssh. eg:

```
user:~$ rsync -a randomfile 192.168.1.11:./
Permission denied, please try again.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
```

yet,

```
user:~$ rsync -a randomfile 192.168.1.10:./
```

works as expected.

My thinking is it is more about SSH permissions than the paths themselves, but they obviously have something to do with it... except (as I've said countless times) paths and permissions **appear** to be uniform across the servers.

Comment: what is ouput of `echo $PATH` in both case ?

Comment: Note you need to single-quote on the local side to avoid local expansion of `$PATH`: `ssh user@192.168.1.11 'echo "$PATH"'`.

Comment: identical in both cases: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: How about `which rsync` interactively on `192.168.1.11`? If the shell is Bash, you can also try `type -a rsync`.

Comment: identical on both again, logging into each machine I get he same results: `/bin/rsync`... using `type -a rsync` just adds another path `/usr/bin/rsync` but again, identical

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1017772/432690).